# List of CSS vendor prefixes?

Tags: css, vendor-prefix

Besides the following list, are there other CSS vendor prefixes that are used for *web development*? Are my definitions correct? Should I be more specific about mobile browsers (mobile Webkit, e.g.)

- `-khtml-` (Konqueror, *really* old Safari)
- `-moz-` (Firefox)
- `-o-` (Opera)
- `-ms-` (Internet Explorer)
- `-webkit-` (Safari, Chrome)

Answer (score 104, accepted):

These are the ones I'm aware of:

- `-ms-` Microsoft
- `mso-` Microsoft Office
- `-moz-` Mozilla Foundation (Gecko-based browsers)
- `-o-`, `-xv-` Opera Software
- `-atsc-` Advanced Television Standards Committee
- `-wap-` The WAP Forum
- `-webkit-` Safari, Chrome (and other WebKit-based browsers)
- `-khtml-`, `-konq-` Konqueror browser
- `-apple-` Webkit supports properties using the -apple- prefixes as well
- `prince-` YesLogic
- `-ah-` Antenna House
- `-hp-` Hewlett Packard
- `-ro-` Real Objects
- `-rim-` Research In Motion
- `-tc-` Tall Components

These are officially listed in the [CSS 2.1 Specification, informative section 4.1.2.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#vendor-keyword-history).

Comment: Wow, nice list. I haven't thought of Prince in a while! I'm particularly interested in web development, so perhaps we could split the ones (like Prince) that wouldn't be viewed in a web context. In what context is `-xv-` an opera extension? I hadn't even heard of that one.

Comment: When you look in the computed styles in Opera Dragonfly, `-xv-` appears to be voice related: [http://img46.imageshack.us/img46/2715/operadragonflystylevend.png](http://img46.imageshack.us/img46/2715/operadragonflystylevend.png). Also see here for documentation: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028362/browser-specific-css-attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028362/browser-specific-css-attributes).

Comment: XP1, what is the -icab vendor prefix used for?

Comment: This list seems to be coming from the [W3C's CSS 2.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#vendor-keyword-history)

Comment: @Grant I looked thru the support docs and blog.  Couldn't find any mention of unique vendor prefixes for iCab.

Comment: @dcc It [probably doesn't exist](http://danielfriesen.name/blog/2011/01/05/css3-border-radius-and-vendor-prefix-fud/), actually.

Comment: `-fso`: Found in inteljIdia?

Answer (score 1):

While not in the direct context of web development, JavaFX uses a vendor prefix for its use of CSS as well: `-fx-`.