# browser specific css attributes

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, safari

Where can I find a complete "browser specific css attributes" reference?

I mean some attributes such as `-moz-border-radius` that is just for Firefox or `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio`. These examples work just in a specified web browser. I want a complete reference for these attributes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each vendor should maintain a list of custom CSS extensions.  The ones I've found are linked below.

- [Mozilla (Firefox)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS_Reference/Mozilla_Extensions)
- [Opera](http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/presto28/css/o-vendor/)
- [Safari](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001266-SW1) (merged with standard CSS properties)
- [Internet Explorer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/09/08/microsoft-css-vendor-extensions.aspx) (outdated)

Ones I can't find ...

- Chrome (same engine as Safari, some slight differences in vendor extensions supported)

Answer (score 4):

[Peter Baverloo's table](http://peter.sh/experiments/vendor-prefixed-css-property-overview/) is the best reference I have been able to find for all browsers in one single page.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [css3files](http://www.css3files.com/). It's a site that talks about all popular css3 functions, in what browsers they work and what code you need to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this page: http://caniuse.com/

It also shows most, if not all, HTML5 and CSS3 features and their support.