# Is -webkit-focus-ring-color a CSS variable?

Tags: css, webkit

Browsing through default Webkit CSS [here](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/WebCore/css/html.css) I noticed the following piece of code:

```
:focus {
    outline: auto 5px -webkit-focus-ring-color
}
```

It seems `-webkit-focus-ring-color` is a variable of some sort. I thought CSS could *not* have variables. What is going on here?

Comment: This is a vendor specific implementation detail only used by webkit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's called a *vendor prefix*. You can check out a previously answered question about a list of VPs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411026/list-of-css-vendor-prefixes).

Regarding your question of *variables in CSS*, there is a way to use variables in CSS development. I'm sure there are other ways, but the most popular are [{less css}](http://lesscss.org/) and [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/).

Comment: To be clear, those are javascript libraries that fiddle with the CSS.

Comment: Or one can simply parse css as php and use php variables to insert stuff in the css file serverside, based on for instance what browser is being used. Not a very good way to do it, just saying it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be technically pedantic, it’s a keyword (just like `auto` or `red`), not a variable.

And [as vonkly says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575006/variables-in-css/7575058#7575058), it’s a keyword with a vendor prefix.

Apple’s documented it e.g. [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/safaricssref/articles/standardcssproperties.html#//apple_ref/css/property/color), where they describe it as a constant.