# Checkbox not highlighted on hover in Chrome 32

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, webpage-rendering

When I hover over a checkbox or it's label in Firefox or IE, the checkbox enters an active state where it is highlighted, indicating that a click will affect it.  However this doesn't appear to be working chrome for me.

Here's some very, very simple code:

```html
<label>
    <input type="checkbox"/>
    Sample Check Label
</label>
```

### [Here's a fiddle to try out](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/K4cXa/)

Here's an example of how checkboxes are rendering in all browsers:

[image: screenshots]

I'm using chrome 32.0.1700.76 m

- Is this an issue other people are having with chrome?
- If other people aren't having this issue, any ideas what could be causing it (extension, add on)
- Is this actually the way chrome chooses to render checkboxes?

  - If so, are there any workarounds for cross browser consistency?

Comment: *"Is this actually the way chrome chooses to render checkboxes?"* - Yes.

Comment: Looks to be default behaviour for me at least. I don't see a problem here - the user can always click on the checkbox itself if unsure, although that still doesn't highlight it

Comment: Unfortunately, Chrome has switched to non-native checkboxes (cf. ["Chrome 32 vs Windows"](http://winsupersite.com/cloud/chrome-32-vs-windows)). The highlight effect is most probably handled by Windows itself and therefore doesn't appear on those non-native checkboxes (unless Chrome also tries to mimic Windows' default behavior)

Comment: On a related note I'm hating Chrome 32's new scrollbars.

Comment: @j08691, there's an [app for that](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/win7-scrollbars/cifcnoebhbpdndjendfkpehpfbglgfkc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since apparently chrome is doing this [intentionally](http://winsupersite.com/cloud/chrome-32-vs-windows) to move away from native controls, here's a way to change the default behavior in chrome.

- Use the CSS [Attribute Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to target `input` with `[type=checkbox]`
- Use the CSS [`:hover` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) to conditionally apply values when hovering
- Use the Chrome [Vendor Prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5411098/1366033) to only target `-webkit-` browsers<sup>†</sup>
- Style with [`Box-Shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow), using the `inset` option so the shadow goes inwards

Add this CSS:

```css
input[type=checkbox]:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px 2px rgba(82,168,236,.6);
}
```

### [Here's a Demo in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/K4cXa/3/)

Here's an **example***:

[image: screenshot]

†The webkit prefix will also apply to safari browsers
**There have been prettier things in the world, but I'd still rather have this than nothing*

Comment: You mean "moving away from native controls", not moving away from **non-** native controls"?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome's new rendering has quite a few UI changes.

Just use a simple CSS `pseudo-class` to fix it.

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4bpbr/3/

**HTML**

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox"/>
    Sample Check Label
</label>
```

**CSS**

```
input:hover {
    background:#CCC;
}
```