# CSS transition and perspective doesn't give same result in chrome/ie and firefox

Tags: html, css, transform, css-transforms

I'm playing with CSS perspective and I don't get the same result between firefox and chrome/ie.
I want it to work as in chrome/ie (the flipping panel doesn't go over the non flipping cat when it closes).

Here the codepen.io I made for the question :http://codepen.io/mourtazag/pen/cdAuL

Thanks !

Comment: maybe you will find your answer here.


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411026/list-of-css-vendor-prefixes

Answer (score 0):

you may not be using proper vendor prefix.

-khtml- (Konqueror, really old Safari)

-moz- (Firefox)

-o- (Opera)

-ms- (Internet Explorer)

-webkit- (Safari, Chrome)

and also dont forget to use default code, i.e. code without vendor prefix.

Comment: I think I used the right prefixes, ie, -moz- one for firefox ! :(