# How To Move/Animate A DIV Background Image Smoothly Vertical?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I have a DIV with some text in it. I added a background image on it. Now I want to keep scrolling my DIV background image from bottom to top smoothly. For this purpose, I searched for the code and I found some codes...

```
<style type="text/css">
#moving_bg {
background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/zF1zrkC.jpg');
background-repeat:repeat-y;
color:#FFFFFF;
width:1000px;
height:300px;
text-align:center;
}
</style>
<div id="moving_bg">
<h2>This is my DIV text that I want do not want to move/animate.</h2>
</div>
```

CODE 1:) **http://jsfiddle.net/ZTsG9/1/** This is a code that I found but this one have some problems with me. First of all its moving horizontally and second is that its making image width doubled to 200% that I dont want also.

CODE 2:) **http://jsfiddle.net/hY5Dx/3/** This one is also moving horizontally and  not making the image width doubled. But its `JQuery` that I dont want.

I want only `CSS3` or `JavaScript` with `HTML` code to move my background image in DIV from bottom to top without doubling the image width. Is this possible in these two web languages...???

Comment: then please remove the `jquery` tag..

Comment: requestAnimationFrame is your friend for smooth animation in modern browsers, don't use setInterval, timers are flaky. modified your fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/hY5Dx/100/

Comment: @Brunis That's cool but I don't want it in JQuery. Anyway nice share...

Comment: So you set the style with VanillaJS: http://jsfiddle.net/hY5Dx/103/

Comment: @Brunis You should share this in answer as you have the Cross-Browser lightweight code...

Comment: i added my fiddle as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Muhammad's request i'll add my fiddle as an answer.

VanillaJS using requestAnimationFrame for that butter smooth slide :)

http://jsfiddle.net/hY5Dx/103/

Code to please SO:

```
var y = 0;
requestAnimationFrame(move);
var body = document.body;
function move(){
    y++;
    body.style.backgroundPosition = '0 ' + y + 'px';
    requestAnimationFrame(move);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can get away with using 2 divs you can get it to work like this:

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZTsG9/28/)**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.outer {
    height:100%;
    overflow: hidden; /* hide the overflow so .inner looks like it fits in the window*/
}
.inner {
    height:200%; /* the inner div will need to be twice as tall as the outer div */
    width:100%;
    -webkit-animation:mymove 5s linear infinite;
    animation:mymove 5s linear infinite;
    background-image: url('http://static1.360vrs.com/pano-content/judith-stone-at-sunset-east-farndon/640px-360-panorama.jpg');
    background-size: 100% 50%; /* 50% height will be 100% of the window height*/
}
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
    from {
        background-position: 0% 0%;
    }
    to {
        background-position: 0% -100%;
    }
}
@keyframes mymove {
    from {
        background-position: 0% 0%;
    }
    to {
        background-position: 0% -100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems kinda overkill using keyframes for a simple linear infinite slide?

Comment: @Brunis If you have a better solution, new answers are always welcome.

Comment: @Brunis Its the best one in CSS. Do you have better then this?

Answer (score 1):

*As there is too much comments after @Skynet answer, here I add the one I wrote following his base structure.*

So in CSS, you can make use of [animation CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation)
This property still is [vendor-prefixes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411026/list-of-css-vendor-prefixes%5D) dependant.

Basically for what you want to do, you have to animate the [background-position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position) property, only on y axis.

Here is the CSS code

```
/* Following defines how the animation 'mymove' will run */
@keyframes mymove {
    /* 0% is the beginning of animation */
    0% {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
    /* This is the end… where we set it to the size of the background image for y axis (0 being the x axis) */
    100% {
        background-position: 0 860px;
    }
}
/* same for webkit browsers */
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
    0% {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 0 860px;
    }
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.view {
    color:#FFFFFF;
    height: 366px;
    text-align:center;
    /* Here we assign our 'mymove' animation to the class .view, we ask it to last 3 seconds, linearly (no ease at start or end), and repeating infinitely */
    animation: mymove 5s linear infinite;
    /* again webkit browsers */
    -webkit-animation:mymove 5s linear infinite;
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/zF1zrkC.jpg');
}
```

[And here we are.](http://jsfiddle.net/Kaiido/D8xP4/6/)

The other answers are ok but as mentionned, using multiple divs isn't always possible and the use of requestAnimationFrame() is also browser specific ([Paul Irish has good polyfill for this)](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/1579671).
Furthermore, I'm not sure incrementing a var infinitely is a good solution : it will block near 6100000px, and its much more code to change the speed or to take control over the animation.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="view" style="background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/zF1zrkC.jpg')">According to a new report from AnandTech.</div>





    html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.view {
    color:#FFFFFF;
    width:1000px;
    height:300px;
    text-align:center;
    -webkit-animation:mymove 5s linear infinite;
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    animation:mymove 5s linear infinite;
    background-size: 200% 100%;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
@keyframes mymove {

    100% {
        transform: translate3d(0px, -400px, 0px);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes mymove
/* Safari and Chrome */
 {

    100% {
        transform: translate3d(0px, -400px, 0px);
    }
}
```

check [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E27L3/)

Comment: WoW, Just edited the other codes. I shared other codes that I checked myself but that are not what I want. Please read the question again...

Comment: @MuhammadHassan check again

Comment: @Skynet You one is now moving whole image. I want it to repeat-y without any break...

Comment: @Kaiido You one is 90% ok but its giving a blink while repeating image on y-axis.

Comment: animation: mymove 1s linear infinite;
-webkit-animation:mymove 1s linear infinite;

If we speed up the animation then i think the 10% flaw what @Kaiido is lacking i code could be overcome.

Comment: Hum, actually it's the background-position wich made those jumps. You have to set it to the height of your pic (here "860px") : 
http://jsfiddle.net/Kaiido/D8xP4/4/

Comment: Do you mean the code doesn't work? You're using a webkit browser so you need the [-webkit prefix][http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411026/list-of-css-vendor-prefixes]  http://jsfiddle.net/Kaiido/D8xP4/6/