# Transform scale and border radius

Tags: css, google-chrome, transform, scale

I try add hover effect to image and I have a problem.

In Firefox all is ok:

[image]

But in Chrome is a problem:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<div class="photo">
   <img src="images/photo.jpg" alt="">
</div>



.photo {
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   border: 10px solid $white-color;
   overflow: hidden;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: -50px;
   left: calc(50% - 110px);
   @include border-radius(50%);

   img {
     max-width: 100%;
     height: auto;
     @include scale(1);
     @include transition(.3s ease-in-out);

     &:hover {
       @include scale(1.2);
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Seeing your `@includes` would be of help.

Answer (score 0):

for Chrome use prefixes
for this specific use -webkit-transform: scale();

also add it to transition property

for the future read
[List of CSS vendor prefixes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411026/list-of-css-vendor-prefixes)

Comment: This is my mixins:


`// Generic transform
@mixin transform($transforms) {
  -moz-transform: $transforms;
  -o-transform: $transforms;
  -ms-transform: $transforms;
  -webkit-transform: $transforms;
  transform: $transforms;
}

// Scale
@mixin scale($scale) {
  @include transform(scale($scale));
}

// Transition
@mixin transition($transition...) {
  -moz-transition: $transition;
  -o-transition: $transition;
  -webkit-transition: $transition;
  transition: $transition;
}`

Comment: I have `-webkit-transform` and `-webkit-transition:`

Comment: You added prefixes for tansform, added for transition but didnt for transform scale 

check if this works
http://codepen.io/malikowy/pen/VPPyyq

formated it first in Atom for easier to read version, then saved with Prepros to check for errors, I deleted @include from scale mixin

Answer (score 0):

```
    <style>
        .photo{
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            border: 10px solid #fff;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: absolute;
            border-radius: 50%;
        }

        .photo img {
            max-width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            transition(.3 s ease-in-out);
        }

        .photo img:hover {
            transform: scale(1.2);
         }


    </style>

<div class="photo">
    <img src="images/photo.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```